# Stop UIToolbar from Disappearing in Landscape Orientation - iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

Not sure why this happens or how to stop it, my `UIToolBar` on the details `viewcontroller` is only visible during portrait view. I want it visible at all orientations. How do I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I encountered the same problem by just dragging a UIToolBar on to my view and docking it on the top of the window. It showed up in landscape but not portrait. Interface Builder - at least the one embedded in Xcode 4 - doesn't seem to do the right thing with the resize masks.

While Kshitiz's answer above will work, it has a couple of flaws. As coded, it does not support all four orientations. More importantly, it's not resolution independent.

A better solution is briefly described in enamrik's comment, so credit should go to him/her. Here are the steps:

1. Select the tool bar in Interface Builder.
2. Open the Size inspector.
3. In the Autosizing box, select the left, right and top "i-beams" on the exterior of the square. This keeps the position of the toolbar fixed relative to the sides of the view when the view is resized.
4. Inside the Autosizing square, select the horizontal line with arrows on both ends. This causes the size of the toolbar to change in sync with the parent view.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It solved my problem and the tool bar is coming in landscape mode too...but my problem is when I am adding a UIBarButtonItem in the right corner of tool bar which I have added in portrait mode. The UIBarButtonItem item is coming in middle of tool bar when I going in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

in your this function of view controller reset view frame bro

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
    if (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 703,768);    

        } else {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        }


    return YES;
}
```

and your tool bar frame too
good luck

Comment: That looks like a hack; a solution that'll do until the real solution gets here. I thought there must be a property on the UISplitViewController to stop it from hiding the toolbar but I still haven't found one. This is depressing. Thanks though, your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: anyway the job is done , i was troubled with same problem some time ago and i found this one

Comment: Just wanted to give an update. All I needed to do to stop the toolbar from disappear was to mess around with the autoResizeMask in interface builder. After setting the width and margin top, left and right (by clicking the light red arrays to make them dark red), the toolbar no longer disappeared when rotated. This makes sense as I need to tell the toolbar how it will be resized and repositioned in relation to it's parent view when the parent view changes.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem when I add UIPickerView programmatically and add UIToolBar for the PickerView. Just need to add `[.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]` for the UIPickerView. eg:-

```
let statTypePicker = UIPickerView()
```

And then add

```
 self.statTypePicker.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
```